# How to permanently change the icon of terminal in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

In Visual Studio Code, the icon for **JavaScript Debug Terminal** has been changed to that of **powershell**! 
[image]

How can I permanently set it back to debug icon?
Like this:
[image]

Comment: weird. I get a bash icon for mine. historically related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/975 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128251

Comment: @user: Thank you for sharing the vs-code issue.

Comment: issue ticket raised at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182303. I'll write up an answer here once the bug is fixed.